# Does the Webkit console not know how to work with observables in KnockOut?

Tags: javascript, webkit, console, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

Let me explain it step by step

1. A function of mine is doing a `console.log()` on an Knockout observable in a model
2. Console says `Array(0)`
3. However, at that point I click that `array(0)` it displays items. So it is not true there are no items in the array
4. In between my `Console.log()` and the moment I click the `array(0)`, the `observableArray()` has been filled with items, and thus is not empty anymore.

My question here is, is this functionality of the console wrong? Should it actually display the items, or just display an empty array. Why does this happen in the first place?

Or look it at the other way around, should the console update the `array(0)` with `array(50)` when there are 50 items in it.

And how do I overcome this issue? Code snippet on working with that:

```
var myModel = function(){
    this.myArray = ko.observableArray();
}

var model = new myModel();
console.log(model.myArray());

model.myArray.push('item');
```

Comment: Since you're logging a plain array, it cannot be an issue with ko or observables. I assume the console simply doesn't refresh its display when the items change; It has a similar behavior for DOM attributes, etc sometimes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this issue, it helped me to add the data to another variable, and log that through console.log().

Example:

```
var myArray = [];

var logArray = myArray;
console.log(logArray);
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if I understand correctly, but your console log only displays the items as they were when you made the call.  So after you push an item onto the array, if you made another console log it would reflect the latest changes.   Just because it is an observable doesn't mean that the console log will update automatically.

To have the console log 'hook' into any changes you would have to create a custom binding with the log in the binding call.

Comment: Not exactly. The console does kinda update a bit. But visually it displays array(0), but it is clickable and items do show up. So the content is update, the array(0) not.